# Relying on a number of TestExecutionListeners in order to populate an in-memory DB and run integration tests

Tags: spring-test

I have a number of **Spring integration tests** that all somehow need to use data (from an in-memory database).

The tests all require subtly different data sets so that as of now I use plain Spring `@Component` helper classes (located in the test package hierarchy) that insert the data right from the test methods as show below:

```
@Autowired
private SomeHelper someHelper;

@Test
public void someIntegrationTest(){
  //Arrange
  someHelper.insertSomeData();
  ...

  //Act
  ...

  //Assert
  ...
}
```

I find this solution not very clean nor very beautiful and I am seeking to improve it or replace it with an alternative solution....

Would it be a good idea to implement a hierarchy of **`TestExecutionListeners`**  where common required data would be inserted by the base class and data specific for the individual tests would be inserted by the subclasses of the base class??

If relying on TestExcutionListener in order to insert test data is not a good idea, then what could be a reliable and viable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Spring Test DbUnit](https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit) (and the related [blog announcement](http://coderphil.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/database-testing-using-dbunit-spring-and-annotations/)).

I think it will satisfy your needs.

Regards,

Sam

Comment: Thanks again for replying Sam. I would be grateful if you could give me your advice regarding the pros and cons of populating the db using the application repositories/daos (as is done by my app now) vs using xml files (as with db unit). Can using xml files hinder refactoring when the data is more complex than just a couple of lines in a single table?